# Obtener valor maximo y minimo usando psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta a una base de datos con el fin de obtener el valor máximo y mínimo de una columna en un rango determinado de fechas pero no obtengo ningun resultado.

Para conectarme a la base de datos estoy utilizando el módulo psycopg2

Esta es la query que quiero ejecutar:

```
querySentence = """
            SELECT MIN (t."NOMBRE_CAMPO") , MAX(t."NOMBRE_CAMPO")
                FROM {} t 
                JOIN "TABLA_B" tb
                    on t."NOMBRE_CAMPO" = tb."NOMBRE_CAMPO"
                WHERE  tb."Fecha" < %s AND tb."Fecha" >= %s;"""
```

Y aquí donde intento extraer los resultados:

```
postgresCursor.execute(
                sql.SQL(querySentence)
                .format(sql.Identifier(table)),
                [minDate, minDate])
resultado = postgresCursor.fetchone()
```

La query que estoy formando obtenida mediante:

```
print(postgresCursor.mogrify(sql.SQL(querySentence)
                .format(sql.Identifier(table)),
                [maxDate , minDate]))
```

La he probado a ejecutar directamente sobre la base de datos y si que obtengo el resultado correctamente.

Esta es la que obtengo:

```
SELECT MIN (t."NOMBRE_CAMPO") , MAX(t."NOMBRE_CAMPO")
              FROM "TABLA" t 
              JOIN "TABLA_B" tb
                  on t."NOMBRE_CAMPO" = tb."NOMBRE_CAMPO"
              WHERE  tb."Fecha" < '2021-01-01'::date AND tb."Fecha" >= '2020-12-01'::date;
```

En cambio en mi código obtengo `(None, None)`

Realmente no sé si es por el tamaño de la base de datos o si estoy realizando algo mal.
También he intentado acceder al resultado mediante resultado[0] pero sigo obteniendo el None.